# react native Could not find com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-volley

I use react native 66 when run `yarn android` got the Error

> yarn run v1.22.17
> $ react-native run-android
> info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
> Jetifier found 1428 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
> info JS server already running.
> info Installing the app...
> Configure project :react-native-firebase
> react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from /Users/ha3an/Documents/Bahrami/phone/homeserviceuser/node_modules/react-native/android
> WARNING:: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.2.
> Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.2 will be used.
> To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
> See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> 39 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 37 up-to-date
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/volley-1.1.1.pom
> - file:/Users/ha3an/.m2/repository/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/volley-1.1.1.pom
> - file:/Users/ha3an/Documents/Bahrami/phone/homeserviceuser/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/volley-1.1.1.pom
> - file:/Users/ha3an/Documents/Bahrami/phone/homeserviceuser/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/volley-1.1.1.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/volley-1.1.1.pom
> - https://www.jitpack.io/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/volley-1.1.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-google-places > com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> BUILD FAILED in 25s

and build.qradle file is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

i try use jcenter on my build.gradle file it's build successfully but got error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.../phone/homeserviceuser/http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.aloosalamati.homeserviceuser&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/.../phone/homeserviceuser/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:919:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/.../phone/homeserviceuser/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:992:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Server._processRequest (/.../phone/homeserviceuser/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:403:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/.../phone/homeserviceuser/http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.aloosalamati.homeserviceuser&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
}
```

i google it but can not find any solution  for it

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Added these lines in project gradle all projects section

```
        jcenter() //by adding this
        google() 
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com" // by adding this
     }
```

Full code

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com" // specifically this worked 
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In *node_modules\react-native-google-places\android build.gradle* file

replace below

```
  > implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0
```

by this :-

```
  >implementation('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0') {
   exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
   }
   implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
```

Source : https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places/issues/301

Answer (score 0):

i use `jcenter` and it's work fine

Comment: This answer is incomplete and needs more details.